# Incrementally append data from a large number of files given column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have over 100 files of 100 MB each. They all have the same structure, and contain one column called 'category'. I need to group the contents of all those files by 'category'.

Example of the files:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | alpha |
| ... | ... | ... | alpha |
| ... | ... | ... | beta |
| ... | ... | ... | gamma |

So, row 1 and 2 need to end up in a file called alpha. Row 3 and 4 need to end up in a file called beta and gamma, respectively.

Unfortunately, I can not load them all in cache to perform a pd.groupby function: the files are too large and numerous.

My idea is to initialize the destination files and loop through the source files to incrementally append them to the destination files. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can initialize the destination files then loop through your files and line by line decide where you want them to end up.

Something like this for all files:

```
destination_dict = {"alpha":"alphafilename","beta":"betafilename","gamma":"gammafilename"}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       category = line.split()[-1] #since category should be the last string
       with open(destination_dict[category], 'a') as dest_file:
          dest_filefile.write(line)
```